# Force Apex generated events to sync with Gmail/Outlook?

Tags: apex, lightning, event, salesforce-for-outlook, gmail

When events are created with our custom UI, they get inserted via Apex. Apparently, when users have syncing set up, the syncing only occurs if the user creates the event in Salesforce1 or Lightning through the Salesforce UI.

Is there something that can be done in Apex to force the apex generated events to sync to Outlook and Gmail?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Lightning sync, that only works for events created from Lightning UI. All other events, e.g. created via APEX, won't sync.
Workaround is: update the event from UI (silly!).

It's not supported by design, see here: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pMX8QAM

I'm also facing the same issue and, according to SFDC support, there isn't a way to force sync via APEX. Personally, I haven't find a way (so far)

Comment: Dang. I was wondering how they did the sync. Like, there must be some field they are setting that they hid or some such, but maybe not. That's very dumb that we can't do the sync from Apex.

Comment: Event records created by UI or APEX appears to be the same in DB, however there might be a field that is hidden to us (as users).

Personally, I think they have a hook in the UI components to trigger the sync whenever an Event is created/updated/deleted

Comment: Salesforce enabled events sync also for events created via API, starting from winter '19
Here's the release note:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_sales_lightning_sync_api_sync.htm